# Where to find Firefox changelogs for beta versions?

Tags: firefox, browser, version, releases

I've been using firefox Developer edition for a while, and every now and then, I get notified of new Beta versions.

The problem is that if I use the "what's new" option (either from the notification popup, or from the about firefox dialog), it just sends us to the same "base" beta version release notes / changelog, instead of showing specific changes among beta versions. e.g. what changed between beta 5 and 6.

As of today (Oct 13th, 2017), it always redirects to this page:
https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/57.0beta/releasenotes/

Note that for "stable" releases, firefox DOES have different release notes pages for minor and mayor updates. e.g. for version 55, we have:

- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/55.0/releasenotes/
- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/55.0.1/releasenotes/
- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/55.0.2/releasenotes/
- https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/55.0.3/releasenotes/

I've tried changing the url for beta releases to get a specific beta changelog, but such pages don't exist.

I've also googled things among "firefox 57.0b6", "firefox beta changelog", and several similar things, to no avail.

So, where can I find such specific beta version changelogs? And why aren't they easier to find?

I've also tried contacting Firefox for the issue, but still no reply from them. I don't know if I should raise a bug in bugzilla for this particular issue.

Comment: They probably don't release them because it is an unreasonable amount of work for a minor beta release. It would be a lot of work to sift through the code and document the "key" changes in amongst all the minor churn. People who care about beta versions are probably those waiting on bug fixes and would be able to see what is fixed from bugzilla, normal users would not need the cutting edge stuff unless there are features they are specifically waiting for in which case again: bugzilla.

Comment: still, in bugzilla there is not (afaik) a simple way of finding bugs based on in which (beta) version they were fixed.